# Fractional change in the size of a spreading Gaussian wave packet

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, electrons

Let's consider a spreading of a Gaussian wave packet for a free particle for,
$$w=\frac{\hslash k^2}{2m}$$

And I have this equation to calculate the fractional change in the size of the wave packet in one second,
$$|f(x,t)|^2=(\frac{\pi ^2}{\alpha ^2+\beta ^2t^2})^{1/2}e^{-[\alpha (x-v_gt)^2/2(\alpha ^2+ \beta ^2t^2 )]}$$

the packet is an electron and the size of the packet is $$10^{-4};10^{-8}$$.

I couldn't establish a solid connection with these two equations.
I thought that we may perhaps follow the derivation of the second equation from the group velocity which is $$v_g=\frac{dw}{dk}$$ but I don't think that makes a lot of sense does it?

Comment: Are you completely, unequivocally, comfortable with [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet#Dispersive)? You have failed to define *f*, and your expression is wrong/ unnormalized. Show your work. This is an introductory homework problem you ***should*** be able to do in your sleep. What is your problem?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I am not comfortable with it completely that's why I am studying it. I couldn't find a way and that's due to the reason that I do not have a huge grasp on the topic and I am trying to solve these questions to have a better grasp. I am just asking for a guidance.